# Backbone / Marionette CollectionView - Render inside template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I have a collection rendering well using Backbone/Marionette/Mustache.

So `PersonModel` and `PersonView` are working fine.  `PersonView` has a mustache template called `PersonTemplate` that is being loaded perfectly by my `PeopleCollection` and `PeopleCollectionView` and rendering inside a default `tagname: "div"`.

However, I want to render this collection inside of another template so I can put some headers there.

Right now it's essentially:

```
<div> <!-- collection tagName -->
    <div class="person"> <!-- PersonTemplate -->
        <div class="person-name">John</div>
    </div>
    <div class ="person"> <!-- PersonTemplate -->
        <div class="person-name">Dave</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I would like it to be:

```
<div id="people> <!-- CollectionTemplate -->
    <h1>People</h1> <!-- CollectionTemplate -->
    <div class="person"> <!-- PersonTemplate -->
        <div class="person-name">John</div>
    </div>
    <div class ="person"> <!-- PersonTemplate -->
        <div class="person-name">Dave</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I understand I can add these items with jQuery after the fact, but I was hoping to avoid that because my actual `CollectionTemplate` is much more complex than the example given here.

Comment: Have a look at Marionette's CompositeView (http://marionettejs.com/docs/v1.8.5/marionette.compositeview.html), it does exactly what your are looking for (as far as I understand that is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CompositeView is exactly what you need. Here is how I have CompositeView setup for simple notes panel.

Item View for each note:

```
View.NoteRow = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
                template: Handlebars.compile(rowTemplate),
                tagName: "tr",
                className: "row-item",
            })
```

The Composite View:

```
  View.NotesPanel = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
                template: Handlebars.compile(panelTemplate),
                itemView: View.NoteRow,
                itemViewContainer: "tbody",
                className: "panel panel-default button-panel notes-panel",

                events: {
                    "click button#add-note" : "addNote"
                }
  })
```

Now the templates:

panelTemplate:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-9">
                <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Notes</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 button-column">
                <a href="#"><button id="add-note" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Note</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <table id="notes-table" class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>User</th>
            <th>Note</th>


        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And the row template:

```
<td>{{employee_id}}</td>
<td>
    <p>{{note_text}}</p>
    <p><span  class="tooltip-span timestamp" id="account-created" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{created_at}}">{{humanize created_at}}</span></p>
</td>
```

In your CompositeView definition you specifiy what template you want to use (panelTemplate) in my example.  Than you specify which ItemView to use for each model in the collection that composite view holds. (View.NoteRow in my example).  Than you define the container within your template that each ItemView will go into ( I'm each of my ItemViews into )